# Django contact page without sendgrid

Tags: django, email

I have a working django contact page, currently configured to send the mail message to the console, as well as tested with my server. The only issue with using my server settings, is that it uses the pre-configured email in my settings.py to send the message. And I'd like custom email addresses to be entered. I've seen sendgrid is one way of doing this, but I'd like to know if I can achieve this without using a service like sendgrid?

Edit: project code. I'd like for the user to enter their email address in the from_email field and use my server to send the message instead of using service like sendgrid.

**settings.py**

```py
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'server.domain.tld'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@domain.tld'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**forms.py**

```py
    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        from_email = forms.EmailField(
            required=True,
            widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your email address", "class": "heading"}),
            label=''
        )
        subject = forms.CharField(
            required=True,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your subject", "class": "heading"}),
            label=''
        )
        message = forms.CharField(
            required=True,
            widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "Your message here"}),
            label=''
        )
```

**views.py**

```py
    def contact_page_view(request):
        contact_query = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if contact_query.is_valid():
                from_email = contact_query.cleaned_data['from_email']
                subject = contact_query.cleaned_data['subject']
                message = contact_query.cleaned_data['message']
    
                try:
                    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['email@domain.tld'])
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                return redirect('pagesapp:confirm')
        return render(request, 'pagesapp/contact.html', {'contact_sub': contact_query})
```

**contact.html**

```html
      <div class="centre form-container centre-pad mobile-pad">
        <form class="article-form" method="POST">
          <h1 class="gold-card">Email Us</h1>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{contact_sub.as_p}}
          <input type="submit" value="Send email">
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any paid service then you can set up an SMTP server on your hosting and use that configuration on Django settings to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard  `from django.core.mail import send_mail`

Then add this to your `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
# Email Configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "user@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "ourgmailpassword"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

this function will send an email from your gmail address:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def email():
    subject = "Subject"
    message = "Test email"
    recipient_list = ["other@email.com"]
    send_mail(
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
        recipient_list=recipient_list,
        fail_silently=True,
    )

email()
```

Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the Gmail service for the mail.**

> Steps to use Gmail as an email service (Free) in Django:

1: Create a dummy Google account for your contact.
2: Add the following code in settings.py at the bottom.

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "yourdummy@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "dummypassword"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

3: Now in views.py add:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
# now in your function add this code

messageContent = yourcontent
msg = EmailMessage(heading, messageContent, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[list of senders email])
msg.send()
```

4: Enable these things first for the dummy Gmail account:

a: Go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and enable it.
NOTE: First check that you enable this with sign in as your dummy account.
b: Now go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue.

5: You are ready to use Gmail email services for your contact page.

> Bonus:

**If you want to send a mail with an HTML template in Django then use this code in views.py.**

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

# add this code in function:
ctx = {
    'subject': subjectin,
    'userMsg': messagein,
   }

heading = Your heading

messageContent = get_template('yourTemplate.html').render(ctx) #sending value on HTML page through context
msg = EmailMessage(heading, messageContent, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                   [list of emails ])
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

Comment: Hope this helps you with the email on the contact page.

Comment: Does the 'from' setting have to match the EMAIL_HOST_USER setting, or can it be changed in the form?

Comment: I didn't get your point. Please elaborate on it. which 'from' and which 'setting'??

Comment: No, worries, i'm also having trouble explaining the problem i'm facing. My form has a from field that i want the user to enter their address into, so I can respond back. I'll edit my question with my code.

Comment: If you want to take the user's email address then take it from the input as the post method and then store it in the database. Then send as many emails as you want to send to that user.